# Java 8 predicate to select the max

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

This is a two-part question. I'm just learning about predicates in Java 8 and I need to know if there is a predicate that I can pass to the `filter()` method to select the max in a list of integers, as below:

```
List<Integer> numbers = ...
Integer max = numbers.stream()
                     .filter(n -> ???)
                     .getFirst()
                     .get();
```

The bigger question is: can predicates be chained mathematically so that one doesn't have to chain `filter()` or `reduce()` methods, such that the work done in one predicate can be reflected in or passed to the following one, so instead of writing:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(/* predicate1 */
            item -> {
                        // do some work and save in some local variable "var"
                    })
    .filter(/* predicate2 */ var -> ...)
    .reduce(predicate3)
    .getFirst()
    .get();
```

I could write:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(predicate1 "andThen" predicate2 "andThen" reduce by predicate3)
    .getFirst()
    .get();
```

I speculate that there might be a way using the `andThen()` functionality or writing a custom predicate. Can anyone help me understand this better?

Comment: yes e.g. `list.stream().filter(x -> x > 11 && x < 50)`

Comment: You misunderstood my question. That is still a single predicate using the `&&` operator. I want to chain two predicates. Using your example: what if there were two separate predicates `(x -> x > 11)` and `(x -> x < 50)` and I didn't have a way to use the `&&` operator as simply as that? For example, if the two predicates were passed to the caller as method parameters.

Comment: `predicate1.and(predicate2)`?

Comment: @exbuddha *if the two predicates were passed to the caller as method parameter* apply two filters? .filter.filter

Comment: Psst. There is something called [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/Predicate.html). That’s the first place to check whether there is a way to combine predicates. Regarding your first question, a predicate is a function that has to be able to tell whether a particular argument matches the criteria. You can build a predicate that tells whether a particular element is the maximum of an existing list, either by determining the maximum of the list first or by repeating that operation in every test. Neither makes any sense in the context of your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use [`filter(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) to select the maximum value of a `Stream`.

You have multiple other options:

```
stream.max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
stream.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).findFirst();
stream.mapToInt(i -> i).max();
stream.reduce(Integer::max);
```

Yes, `Predicate`s can be chained by [`and(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-). The implementation basically looks like this:

```
Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other) {
    return t -> test(t) && other.test(t);
}
```

You could also simply write your own:

```
static <T> Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T>... ps) {
    return t -> Stream.of(ps).allMatch(p -> p.test(t));
}
```

Usage:

```
stream.filter(and(i -> i > 11, i -> i < 50))
```

You can apply multiple filters, so you usually chain the calls:

```
stream.filter(i -> i > 11).filter(i -> i < 50)
```

Do you understand what [`reduce(BinaryOperator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) does? You cannot put a `Predicate` in there.
I have already used it above as an option to get the maximum value.